# django allowed_hosts error for www domain and ip address

Tags: python, django

django 1.6

I've got my webserver to redirect www requests to the non-www equivalent. i.e. www.domain.com goes to domain.com

i've got django setup to email me any errors

i'm getting a bunch of errors that look like:

> [Django] ERROR: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.domain.com'.You may
>   need to add u'www.domain.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS

or

> [Django] ERROR:
>   Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '< ip address >'.You may need to add u'< ip
>   address >' to ALLOWED_HOSTS

but the content of the emails is simply:

> No stack trace available
>
> Request repr() unavailable.

I know the redirect is working because if i attempt to visit www.domain.com i get redirected to domain.com

**I'd like to better inspect the request object to understand how the requests are getting to django.** the only requests that should be getting forwarded to django should be the ones going to domain.com.
Does anyone know how i might go about this?

or even better if someone knows what is going on here that would be great.

As requested here is the nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen <ip address>:80;
    server_name "";
    return 444;
}


server{
    listen <ip address>:80;

    server_name www.domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}

#HTTPS server
server{
    listen <ip address>:80;
    listen <ip address>:443 ssl;
    server_name domain.com;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  unix:<path to socket file>;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;    
    }

    if ($ssl_protocol = ""){
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't recognize the issue so perhaps this question is unnecessary to someone familiar with it, but what web server are you using and in what way do you have it configured to redirect www requests?

Comment: i'm using nginx. i can post exact config later, but i basically just followed various guides you get when you google "nginx redirect www"

Comment: I think we need to see your web server config, its not really a django problem.

Comment: i agree that django is behaving as expected. I'm just saying i'd like to inspect the request object so that I can better determine where the requests are coming from. e.g. source ip, user agent, etc

Answer (score 1):

The [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) setting in django inspects the `Host` header in your HTTP request, which is generated by the browser when it sends the request.

In your Nginx config you are (presumably) using a URL rewrite not an HTTP redirect.

If that *is* the case, then the redirect is essentially internal to the server.  The original `Hosts` header in the request sent by your browser will still have its original value.

The correct config for Nginx would be something like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.domain.com;
    return       301 http://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;
    ...django server config...
}
```

This will cause an HTTP 301 redirect to be returned to your browser, and the browser will send a new request with the correct `Host` header.

Comment: i'll post nginx conf later, but am definitely doing a redirect, not a rewrite.
If memory serves, the www.domain.com config looks identical to what you have above.

Comment: Open chrome, open developer tools, open the Network tab, tick the Preserve log box, and browse to www.domain.com.  You should be able to see the request, the redirect response, and the resulting second request.  If you click the two requests, you can see the request headers sent for each one. Check the `Host` headers.

Comment: yes, thanks. I checked this already which is why i said i'm not doing a rewrite.